# Get information Kubernetes Namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, monitoring

I am trying to collect some information regarding the kubernetes namespaces.
I found a command where you can see some information.

```
kubectl describe resourcequota -n my-namespaces
```

I have as return:

```
Name:                       gke-resource-quotas
Namespace:                  tms-prod
Resource                    Used  Hard
--------                    ----  ----
count/ingresses.extensions  0     5k
count/jobs.batch            0     10k
pods                        68    5k
services                    44    1500
```

However I need information like:

```
CPU request
CPU Limit
Memory request
Memory Limit
Service (count)
Pods (Count)
Phase
```

I studied a little and saw that it is possible to create ResourceQuota to get this information. However I did not understand very well its operation.

Could anyone get this data?

Comment: Have you checked `kubectl describe nodes`? I think it has all the information that you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. run first `kubectl get quota`
2. then it will display quotas available
3. then run `kubectl describe quota <quota name>`

if you don't have any custom quota then you can create it as describe from https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/

Comment: Can I create quotas without any problems? Won't it change the way my Kubernetes work?